# Is it possible to graph quadratic equations with i as a coefficient?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, quadratics

In my highschool Algebra II class, we are studying quadratic equations.  I was curious if it was possible to graph a quadratic equation with i as a coefficient. Examples: $$ix^2+3x+9$$ $$x^2+(5+i)x+6$$ $$(6i+7)x^2+(3i+5)x+i$$

Comment: You graph *real* functions in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. *Complex* functions can only be "graphed" in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^4$).

Comment: You can graph any complex function, but you can't graph it on the real axis, if that's what you mean.

Comment: There are many kinds of graph. Representing three dimensions on a page is tricky and may require some creativity. Representing four dimensions is even trickier. It depends how you choose to do it. For example, see the "complex map" of $ix^2+3x+9$ at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(z)+%3D+i*z%5E2%2B3*z%2B9 and $(6i+7)x^2+(3i+5)x+i$ at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(z)%3D(6i%2B7)z%5E2%2B(3i%2B5)z%2Bi -- that's one kind of graph.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, they were helpful